# Different html files and Same controller Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Can more than one HTML files have a single controller in angular js?
eg:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/users",{
        templateUrl: "/project/views/users.html"
        controller: "myCtrl",
        resolve: {}
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/admin",{
        templateUrl: "/project/views/admin.html"
        controller: "myCtrl",
        resolve: {}
    });
});
```

This is just a rough code, so can you please tell me whether can I use it like this? and why...!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use it like this? Yes, definitely.
Why? : I don't know. Maybe because that is your requirement. xD

Comment: it's showing errors and no errors?

Comment: sorry, it is a typing mistake, it is showing no errors

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using this :

**Template 1 :**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
// Do whatever
</div>
```

**Template 2 :**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
// Do whatever
</div>
```